# Accessing all folders in Flutter assets

Tags: flutter, dart

There are photos in nested folders in my project and I need to folder the photos that way.
When using this in the project, I have to define each folder via pubspect.yaml and this causes both tedious and dirty code.
Can't I access images in all folders in assets with a single definition? Please help if you know
[Asset definition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGeFj.png)

```
assets/map/anholt_osmbright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

I just want to define a single line and access the extreme folder thanks to it, as in the path I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

Define the folder.

This will "load" all files inside the "map" folder.

```yaml
assets:
 - assets/map/
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I can only read the photos in the map folder, but I want to access the photos in the subfolders of the map folder.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't "load" everything from a folder, just the files, so, if you want to see all, have to add `assets/map/`, `assets/map/anholt_osmbright`, `assets/map/anholt_osmbright/12`, `assets/map/anholt_osmbright/13`, etc...